# Scene Viewer will not launch AR from link but it will launch with a QR code pointing to that link

Tags: arcore

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Avacados</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ar.marketscale.com/test/test.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <a style="display:none" id="ar-link" href="intent://arvr.google.com/scene-viewer/1.0?file=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/Avocado/glTF/Avocado.gltf&mode=ar_only&link=https://www.google.com&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&title=Acocados#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;S.browser_fallback_url=https://developers.google.com/ar;end;">Avovados</a>
        <footer>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
                if (isMobile) {
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        // $('#ar-link').trigger('click');
                            $('#ar-link').click(function() {
                                this.click();
                            }).click();
                        },1000);
                    });
                } else {
                    window.location.href = "https://ar.marketscale.com/test/testfallback.css"
                }
            </script>
        </footer>
        <!--  Include both scripts below to support all browsers! -->
        <!-- Loads <model-viewer> for modern browsers: -->
        <script type="module"
            src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js">
        </script>

        <!-- Loads <model-viewer> for old browsers like IE11: -->
        <script nomodule
            src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer-legacy.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using Scene Viewer and triggering the explicit intent from HTML. It's running in ar_only. The goal is when you visit this website it launches AR automatically. I have a URL and I have a QR code that points to that URL.

When you scan the QR code it starts AR no problem. When you type in the URL it sends you to the fallback website.  I know the phone is compatible because it works when you scan the QR code. I have also tried this on other phones and it gives me the same results.

I think Javascript is the issue. I'm using it to "click" or run this automatically. Any ideas on what could be going on?

the link is ar.marketscale.com/test/ar_avacado.html

here is a QR code that links to that URL:
[QR CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntiwA.png)

Comment: Why are you loading model-viewer and not using it?

Comment: its a remnant of old code setup I was using. Thanks for the heads up, I will remove.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: the reason is because the "immersive-ar" needs the user permissions. You will notice the following error inspecting your device (chrome://inspect/#devices): "Failed to execute 'requestSession' on 'XRSystem': The requested session requires user activation."